# how to update my own joomla 1.5 components?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, lifecycle, updates

how to update my own joomla 1.5 components?

i have 2 components i made with my team, that we use on our web site.  (on joomla 1.5..... we didn't upgrade for the moment)

we often make updates to fix bugs, to add new featers etc...

to put update on production server , we use FTp, and we change the  files that have to be changed........ needless to say, how bad it is.....

i am looking for joomla component, plugin .... to make me able to make updates on my components/template , faster and safer (i imagine, a Zip file containing what have to  be changed, and a rollback function, that allow to restore a version if there is problems)

All i found is components that allow to update the joomla core (to 2.5 for exemple).

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Akeeba Live Update](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-live-update.html). It's basically a 1 click update system that downloads the update zip you upload to the FTP or other host, then unzips it, updating the extension. The first time you try it out, it might be a bit hard to get used to and will probably take a little trial and error, however its the best and I think only out there at the moment. The likes of Kunena also use this system.

Comment: we tried it, and we finnaly developed our own components for updates (needs some cleanning code ,w'll share it after that)